# USB port identification

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

I have to come up with an architecture for a system where PC communicates to two identical(but independent) micro controllers(in-built usb controller) over 2 USB channels. I don't have experience in USB implementation. My question is How PC will identify these USB channels as different. I will be using third party USB library and device descriptors of which is accessible to edit. Is that enough for PC Application to identify these as separate channels. Or PC Application can handle this without even editing the descriptors??.

Comment: ... The serial numbers of the devices?

Comment: It would be best to change the USB PID and/or details of the descriptors, otherwise software would only be able to differentiate by what USB port they are plugged into, and that is rarely considered significant so may be somewhat challenging.  The main problem with your question is then that you haven't said anything about the host operating system, and if you will use native drivers or some sort of userspace driver abstraction (libUSB or various buggy proprietary ones, etc).  For MCUs, emulating a serial device is not uncommon.

Comment: If the two USB channels have the same VID and PID, the PC can still identify them as different if the devices provide a unique serial number. If the processors have a unique ID available, this is sometimes converted to a USB device serial number string.

Comment: @raforanz  Are you writing the firmware for these two controllers?  Will these controllers bae connected once at a factory?  Or, will a non-technical person be (un)plugging them?

Comment: Considered using the USB HID class? Most OS support HID without the need to develop custom device driver. Each device can provide a distinct HID Report datatype, and application software can search all attached HID decives for the one with the right report format.

Comment: @ChrisStratton , Windows 7 is the Host OS.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I will be writing the firmware but will be using TI's usblib package. it will be used in usb bulk mode. and will be plug and play type.